# How to control views wrapping in Android's GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm wondering why in portrait mode, this android xml is not rendered properly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="5">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/Switch1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="5"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Use only WiFi when sending data?"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="5"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Вкупно собрани податоци: "
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Empty Space 1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView3"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Empty Space 1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView4"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Empty Space 1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</GridLayout>
```

It should look like this:

```
|--1--|--2--|--3--|--4--|--5--|
|      fills all columns      |
|-----------|-----|-----|-----|
|     2     |  1  |  1  |  1  |
|-----------|-----|-----|-----|
```

I find it strange that this is working good in landscape mode, until I insert more text in the Switch or Text Views, so probably the problem is because the content is not wrapping, but as you can see I tried to set `layout_width` to `wrap_content', still it doesn't work... so what else is missing..?

*By the way I'm using Xamarin, but I don't believe it is Xamarin's designer problem, because in runtime I get the same layout that I see in the designer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is that your text of the first `TextView` is too long. If you want the text to wrap when the length of the content increases, usually we can specify width of the view as 0dp (`android:layout_width="0dp"`), so that the grid layout will dynamically calculate the width.

I found that `android:layout_columnWeight="5"` of your `Switch` will effect the layout of the `TextView`s in the second row. Changed your code like following and it works by my side:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="5">
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/Switch1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="5"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Use only WiFi when sending data?"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Вкупно собрани податоци: "
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Empty Space 1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView3"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Empty Space 1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView4"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Empty Space 1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you! 3 days searching around, you really saved me!